# Install python 3.6 mysqlclient for Django project on CentOS

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, centos6

I have successfully installed a Django project on my CentOS 6.9. I have installed the project in a virtual environment which I have created using python3.6 `python3.6 -m venv env` I have activated the virtual env and I am now trying to run the app using;

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

When I run this command I get the following error;

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f7f7c5d67b8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 26, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/softwareix/storefront/models.py", line 10, in <module>
    class Brand(models.Model):
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 331, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 30, in <module>
    'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?' % e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
```

I see that I am missing Python mysql extension or driver. I have attempted to install it as suggested. When I run; `pip install mysqlclient` I get;

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-7g3likz_/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-y1mak800-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,10,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.10 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.o
    gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: Permission denied
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-7g3likz_/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-y1mak800-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /REMOVED/REMOVED/python3.6/env/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7g3likz_/mysqlclient/
```

This does not seem to work. I have tried to install severally packages using yum after searching the internet. I tried to install `yum install python3-devel` but this is not available (`No package python3-devel available.`) and I see it is supposed to be in the epel repository. So I did `yum search python dev` and I get this;

```
dbus-python-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and headers for dbus-python
gstreamer-python-devel.x86_64 : Headers for developing programs that will use gstreamer-python
libimobiledevice-python.x86_64 : Python bindings for libimobiledevice
pyldb-devel.x86_64 : Development files for the Python bindings for the LDB library
python-behave.noarch : Tools for the behavior-driven development, Python style
python-cherrypy.noarch : Pythonic, object-oriented web development framework
python-cherrypy2.noarch : Pythonic, object-oriented web development framework
python-devel.x86_64 : The libraries and header files needed for Python development
python-devel.i686 : The libraries and header files needed for Python development
python-igraph-devel.x86_64 : Development files for igraph
python-imaging-devel.x86_64 : Development files for python-imaging
python-mozdevice.noarch : Mozilla-authored device management
python-pyblock.x86_64 : Python modules for dealing with block devices
python-pyldns.x86_64 : Header files, libraries and development documentation for ldns.
python-pyside-devel.i686 : Development files for python-pyside
python-pyside-devel.x86_64 : Development files for python-pyside
python-tools.x86_64 : A collection of development tools included with Python
python34-devel.i686 : Libraries and header files needed for Python 3 development
python34-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and header files needed for Python 3 development
wxPython-devel.i686 : Development files for wxPython add-on modules
wxPython-devel.x86_64 : Development files for wxPython add-on modules
python-pycxx-devel.noarch : PyCXX header and source files
```

This is what I have tried so far. I am trying to get my Django app running on MySQL but the extension or module does not appear to be installed.

Answer (score 3):

The `gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: Permission denied` diagnostic is fairly clear. Use `which as` to verify you haven't put another file named `as` on your `$PATH`. You want to get to the point where you can successfully compile a simple `hello.c` Hello World program, which involves `gcc` producing assembly code, and `as` turning that into intel x86 object code. Try this:

```
sudo yum install gcc binutils-devel
```

Verify it succeeded by running `which as; as --version` and seeing a banner like "GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.27".

Comment: After running `sudo yum install gcc binutils-devel` successfully; `which as` shows; `/usr/bin/as` For `as --version` I get something like; `GNU assembler version 2.20.51.0.2-5.47.el6_9.1 20100205 .. This assembler was configured for a target of `x86_64-redhat-linux'.`

Comment: Duh! - I had indeed limited permissions on `as` as per this lynis advisory: https://cisofy.com/lynis/controls/HRDN-7222/

Answer (score 0):

You currently do not have permissions to `pip install mysqlclient`.  Since this is centos, you probably don't want to use `pip` (unless you set up a `virtualenv`).  You want to run `yum install mysql-python`

Comment: Running `yum install mysql-python` returns; `No package mysql-python available.` I want to use a virtualenv which I have setup using python 3.6

Comment: Logging in and activating the virtualenv as root and then running `pip install mysqlclient` I managed to get mysqlclient to install. So I just didn't have the permissions. How do I give permissions to my Cpanel users to be able to run `pip install mysqlclient`

Comment: Ahh.  Installing the virtualenv as root was likely you're problem.  You need to see what user the cpanel is running as (I think it is simply cpanel), and give them permissions to the virtualenv.  What I would likely do is: do a pip freeze to se what packages are installed, then create a new virtualenv with the cpanel user (sudo su cpanel, or sudo -u cpanel bash to open a shell as that user).